# injecting shellcode

Tags: shellcode

i have a .cmd file on a webserver with a variable user="...", vulnerable against buffer overflows. I can execute the .cmd file via ssh or via web. 
Now i have this shellcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char sc[] =
         "
          ...
             ";

void main(void)
{

       void(*s)(void);
       printf("size: %d\n", sizeof(sc));
       s = sc;
       s();
}
```

my problem is, i don't know how this all plays together. I know what the Assembler and the C code does, but how do i inject the code into the running cmd file?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat "shellcode "  | nc host cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally have to insert enough data so that your write ends up in part of the program's memory that gets executed. How to do that exactly depends entirely on the structure of the program with the overflow.

But, imagine if the program were specified by this ASM listing:

```
[SECTION .text]

global _start

_start:
;;...
jmpagain: 
jmp next

uname db "username"
next:
mov eax,uname
;;...
jmp jmpagain
```

the string `"username"` is in memory immediately adjacent to an address that the instruction pointer visits. If the program writes some data to that area of memory without checking it's bounds, it will overwrite the code, and anytime the instruction pointer revisits the `next` function, the machine is going to execute whatever data overflowed in that part of memory. Supposing the write you are exploiting starts at the beginning of the string, and stops writing on some condition that provides enough room for you to inject your shellcode, you would prepend a byte string of the same length as `"username"` to your shellcode in the input. Then the beginning of your shellcode would be at the address of the `next` label.

But this is just a simple example demonstration of the basic principle. Actually getting your data to an area of memory that the instruction pointer visits is likely going to be a lot trickier. If you have access to the command file in question, you can debug it and dump the memory and trace how the area of memory is written to to see how you need to overflow the buffer to get to IP reachable memory.

It's important to reiterate that your shellcode not only needs to make it to memory that the instruction pointer passes over, it needs to be correctly aligned in that memory to execute in the way you expect it to. If the instruction pointer lands somewhere in the middle of your code rather than at the beginning of the first instruction, it obviously isn't going to do what you expect it to.